# Azure WebApp AppSetting not overriding my Web.Config Environment Variable

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service

My ASP.NET Core web app defines the environment variable `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` in the web.config file.

It is is to `DEVELOPMENT`, which means `appsettings.development.json` will be used.

I'm expecting this value to be overriden by my my Azure Web App setting :

[image: ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT]

it is empty, which means `appsettings.json` should now be used. However it is not the case and when I log the value of the env variable, it is still set to DEVELOPMENT and `appsettings.development.json` is still used.

What am I doing wrong  ?

Comment: Did you try setting a different value instead of using an empty string? E.g. `PRODUCTION`?

Comment: Yes, same. However I think I figured it out. The environment variable defined in web.config cannot be overridden by the azure web app setting. So I removed it from web.config and now the azure web app setting can be set to Devlopment or empty with immediate effect. Instead of using the web.config variable, I am setting it in my machine's environment variables, and it works just as fine.